# git: distributing private repo to some users?

Tags: git, security

is there a way to give a small group of people a way to get latest code, without being able to write, and have access to the usual set of git features like viewing git log etc.

Or is it enough to just give READ only permission to these users?

Comment: Where is it hosted? You could use SSH keys *or* HTTP authentication, and then check the user to see if they get read, write, or read/write privileges.

Comment: github but it's private repo

Comment: You should be able to add users to it. Or maybe that is just for company's private repos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding GitHub, you can see the different ACL (Access Control Level) at "[What are the different access permissions?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions)"

If you are registering your private repo within [**an organization**](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations), then you would have the possibility to add users with **Read Access Teams**: that team would be able to clone/pull only, not push.
(They can **[fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)**, but the fork itself would be private, since it is a clone of a private repo).

Outside of GitHub (self-hosting repos), the usual way to add fine-grained access control levels is **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/)**.

---

> mainly I am looking to deploy my git repo on the production server by just doing git push

What you can do from a private repo is register a **[webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)**, which will trigger a [JSON payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads). Your production server can listen to it, and pull only where there is a push in the GitHub repo (as [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/619858)).

Comment: any way to make it so that when i do a git push, it will update the production server?

Comment: @KJW I have edited my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to take a look at [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).
to configure gitolite they give you a git-repo called gitolite-admin.

if you then add to `conf/gitolite.conf`

```
repo project
    RW = you
    R  = friend1 friend2
```

you are able to read and write while your friends are only allowed to read from the repo. Auth via ssh public keys.

your friends the can use

```
git clone ssh://git@yourhost.com/project.git
```

Comment: mainly im looking to deploy my git repo on the production server by just doing git push